# Excel VBA - CountIfs - Moving from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I'm working on a `CountIfs` formula for a project and am having a little trouble. I'm pulling data from worksheet **HR Data Detail** and pasting it onto worksheet **HR Data Summary**. At the end of my `CountIfs` formula I have the range `Z2:Z`, which contains the years 2017, 2018, 2019, from worksheet **HR Data Summary**. I want Cell `C2` on **HR Data Summary** to be a box that I can auto-fill in any year. For example, if I put *2018* into `C2` then I want the `CountIfs` formula to pull the data for that specific year.

```
Sub Linking ()

'Defining finRow
Sheets("HR Data Detail". Activate)
Dim finRow As String
finRow = Sheets("HR Data Detail").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets ("HR Data Detail")

'Division 21 Employees
    Sheets("HR Data Summary").Range("L4") = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("V2:V" & finRow), ">0", _
            .Range("S2:S" & finRow), "=21", .Range("L2:L" & finRow), "=January", _
            .Range("H2:H" & finRow), "=Employee", _
            Sheets("HR Data Detail").Range("Z2:Z" & finRow), "'HR Data Summary'!C2")
```

Comment: Note that there is an additional double quote in `Range("A50000"")`. Please verify if it is just a typo.

Comment: Sorry, Just a typo. Everything works except for the last segment of my code.

Comment: There also seems to be a typo with `Sheets("HR Data Detail". Activate)`. You probably meant `Sheets("HR Data Detail").Activate`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding the purpose of this complex COUNTIFS formula -

It seems the problem is with the last range/criteria combo. Try changing

```
Sheets("HR Data Detail").Range("Z2:Z" & finRow), "'HR Data Summary'!C2")
```

to the following:

```
.Range("Z2:Z" & finRow), "=" & Sheets("HR Data Summary").Range("$C$2").Value
```

Comment: This is exactly what I spend all day researching. Thank you so much Deasa. I couldn't find anything showing me how to come up with that last part. You're the best. Matt